# EXC_BAD_ACCESS for assignment of ID to Tile object

Tags: c++, xcode, object, runtime-error, implementation

The implementation for a Tile object (an array of which forms a map object) is as follows

```
#include "Tile.h"

Tile::Tile(){
    isPassable_ = true;
}

void Tile::setID(int ID){
    ID_ = ID;
    Tile::setVals(ID);
}

void Tile::setVals(int ID){
    switch(ID){
        case 1 : Tile::GFX_ = '.'; Tile::name_ = "Grass"; Tile::desc_ = "Some grass";
        default: Tile::GFX_ = '?'; Tile::name_ = "Error"; Tile::desc_ = "Error"; Tile::isPassable_ = false;
    }
}

int Tile::getID(){return ID_;}
char Tile::getGFX(){return GFX_;}
std::string Tile::getName(){return name_;}
std::string Tile::getDesc(){return desc_;}
bool Tile::getIsPassable(){return isPassable_;}
```

Where HEIGHT and WIDTH are constant ints defined in the Map header. However, when the program runs, I receive an error for `ID_ = ID;` saying "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0). Could this be a problem with the way that I'm accessing the Tile objects in its 2D array in the Map object, as follows

```
#include "Map.h"

Map::Map(int buffMap[][WIDTH]){
    for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT-1; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH-1; x++){
            map_[y][x]->setID(1);
        }
    }
    for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT-1; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH-1; x++){
            map_[y][x]->setID(buffMap[y][x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is one you should be able to solve faster with a debugger than by playing 20 questions with SO posters. Bounds look reasonable. Are your arrays defined to be the correct sizes?

Comment: @user1207515 I defined both arrays with the constant ints HEIGHT and WEIGHT, which were initialized in the Map header (before I prototyped the class). The debugger says "this = (Tile *) NULL", (I think) referring to "ID_ = ID;", but I don't understand how passing any value into the function would result in a NULL assignment for the Tile object.

Comment: The debugger is telling you that `map_[y][x]` for some values x and y contains no Tile to be `setID`ed. If (x,y) are (0,0), odds are you didn't put any Tiles in your array of Tiles. If (x,y) are not (0,0), then you didn't put in enough Tiles. Consider defining `map_` with Tiles rather than pointers to Tiles and see if that helps.

Comment: How about showing us how `map_` gets its `Tiles`?  Where is the creation, and where is the assignment?